# setRetainInstance on a fragment that needs a service

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app that has been connecting to a service like this:

```
getActivity().startService(intent);
```

However, I realized that when the orientation changes, the connection to the service is broken and recreated (due to the activity life cycle) and this is not what I want. I read that the right thing to do is to use a fragment and call setRetainInstance(true) on it to make the connection to the service persist. However, since the activity is recreated, getActivity().startService(intent) doesn't make sense, as once the orientation changes the service seems to be associated with a no-longer-existant activity. Is this the time to use getApplicationContext, as it should be the same even after the activity is recreated? Another HOWEVER, If I do that, since I have to start the service in the UI thread like this:

```
        getApplicationContext().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                getApplicationContext().startService(intent);

            }
        });
```

it doesn't work because getApplicationContext() does not have a runOnUiThread function.

Any thoughts on how I can connect to a service from a persistent fragment like this?

Comment: Simply requiring your activity not to unbind on Orientation change means your design has a flaw. The service should be independent and you activity should be okay with a disconnection and re-connection on orientation change.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib Sorry, I don't follow. Disconnect/reconnect takes 10 seconds, and I can't wait for that just because the user rotated the device. Can you elaborate on what you're suggesting?

Comment: 10 seconds? may i ask why?

Comment: Yeah, the connection should be made by the service if it isn't connected (the first time the service is started) but binding and then rebinding to the service shouldn't take 10 seconds each time

Comment: Oh I see. I had just been calling startService and bindService together. I will see what happens if I just call bindService on the already-started service. But does it not matter that the service was started on an activity context that no longer exists?

Comment: @Selecsosi The documentation seems to say that the service will be stopped as soon as all components are unbound from it. If I unbind/rebind when the orientation changes, won't the service get stopped?